# How to change grep and cut commands by only one awk/sed command in the following example?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, ash

I have a file containing:

```
aaa.bbbb0.xxxx0=toto
aaa.bbbb0.xxxx1=toto
aaa.bbbb0.xxxx2=titi
eee.ffff.zzzz=kkkk
```

I want to extract the lines containing the regular expression`"aaa\.bbbb0\.xxxx[0-6]\+=toto"` and then extract the 3rd element in the path. So the output should looks in this way

```
xxxx
yyyy
```

I can get this output using `grep` and then `cut` in this way:

```
cat myfile.txt | grep "aaa\.bbbb0\.xxxx[0-6]\+=toto" | cut -d'=' -f1 | cut -d'.' -f3
```

How I can change the above `grep` and `cut` by only one `sed` command or `awk` command?

Comment: IMHO using a more simple solution (like `cut`) is preferable to using a more complicated solution (like `awk`) whenever possible... You could get rid of the `cat` though (`grep =mmm myfile.txt`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

answer to previous question:

```
awk -F'[.=]' '$4 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/ {print $3}' file
```

answer to current question:

```
$ awk -F'[.=]' '/aaa\.bbbb0\.xxxx[0-6]+=toto/ {print $3}' file
xxxx0
xxxx1
```

Comment: Done but I think you still have problems in your question.

Comment: thank you, this is the simplest awk expression and  it works.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk -F[.=] '/=mmmm/{print $3}' input.txt
```

To match the data of your first edit:

```
awk -F[=] '$2 ~ /^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/{split($1,a,".");print a[3]}' input.txt
```

This will match floating point numbers too

And for second edit

```
awk -F= '/aaa\.bbbb0\.xxxx[0-6]+=toto/{split($1,a,".");print a[3]}' input.txt
```

Comment: is it possible to change `=mmmm` with a regular expression?

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Using `grep` `-P` option to enable PCRE you can get the output by using Positive Lookahead and Lookbehind.</strike>

```
$ cat file
aaa.bbbb.xxxx=4521
ccc.dddd.yyyy=7842
eee.ffff.zzzz=kkkk
```

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=\.)(\w+)(?==\d+$)' file
xxxx
yyyy
```

Another `awk` variant:

```
$ awk -F. '{split($3,a,/=/); if (a[2]~/^[[:digit:]]+$/) print a[1]}' file
xxxx
yyyy
```

Based on updated question:

```
$ awk -F. '/aaa\.bbbb0\.xxxx[0-6]+=toto/{split($3,a,/=/); print a[1]}' file
xxxx0
xxxx1
```

Comment: the ash does not support the -oP option.

Comment: @MOHAMED My bad, I didn't see the `ash` tag clearly. Added an `awk` version.

Comment: @MOHAMED In the question your output does not sync up with your input data. I have added another option which has the same output as your attempt in the question.